# How to change font style on vuestic <va-select> (or vuetify <v-select>)?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuestic, vuestic-admin

I am using Vuestic Admin as a template (based on Vuetify) and my  (similar to ) component is strangely displaying different fonts for the selected option (inside the input field) and the dropdown options to be selected.

Is there a way to set all of them to the same font?
(I tried setting the "font-family" in the style field, but it hasn't worked).

My  with different fonts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqEKj.png

Comment: Do you applied correctly the required assets fonts? https://vuestic.dev/es/getting-started/installation#assets-installation

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and made the following change that resolved it:

In `App.vue`, move the `font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` declaration from the `#app` scope into the `body` selector...

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import "~@/sass/main.scss";
#app {
/* FROM HERE ✂️ */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

body {
  /* TO HERE  */
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: var(--va-background);
}
</style>
```